# Why is LD_LIBRARY_PATH undefined when I run my Node.js script using mocha on macOS?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, mocha.js, node-oracledb

Nice to meet you, i am here to ask a question, i am trying to make unit test using oracledb, but i getting an error because it can't found oracle client, testing i found when i run my test file using mocha one of my oracle variable is undefined and this is probably the reason why my code fail, when i run same file using node command this variable have it real value, someone know what it happening and how to fix it?

---

- node v10.21.0
- mocha 8.0.1
- os macOS Catalina 10.15.5
- oracle 12.2.0.1.0

---

File:

```js
console.log('OCI_LIB_DIR', process.env.OCI_LIB_DIR);
console.log('OCI_INC_DIR', process.env.OCI_INC_DIR);
console.log('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH);
```

```
$ mocha file.js
```

result:

```
OCI_LIB_DIR /Users/lmorales/Documents/instantclient_12_2/
OCI_INC_DIR /Users/lmorales/Documents/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /Users/lmorales/Documents/instantclient_12_2
```

---

```
$ node file.js
```

result:

```
CI_LIB_DIR /Users/lmorales/Documents/instantclient_12_2/
OCI_INC_DIR /Users/lmorales/Documents/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include
LD_LIBRARY_PATH undefined
```

[screenshot with evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMVun.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apple macOS's SIP stops variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH being passed down to subshells (This was noted in node-oracledb issue [#231](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/231)).   The node-oracledb install doc has never recommended LD_LIBRARY_PATH on macOS, and stopped recommending DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH many versions ago.

Also I notice you are setting OCI* variables that haven't been needed for several years.

Please read the installation documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instosx for current ways to install node-oracledb.
You can use the new initOracleClient() call, create a sym link in your node_modules/oracledb/build/Release directory, or put the Instant Client in /usr/local/lib - see the doc.

Comment: yes, because i am using oracle 12, so we need use too old configuration

Comment: The Oracle Client version has nothing to do with it. You can still use Oracle client 12 with the latest version of node-oracledb. (But if your database versions are 11.2 or later, then you could / should update your Oracle Client version)